# error in main.xml file:Error parsing xml:unbound prefix

Tags: android

my Environment is 
eclipse :3.2
android:2.3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:isScrollContainer="true" 
   android:keepScreenOn="true" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView 
  android:text="The Company" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_weight="1" 
  style="@layout/main" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:textSize="40dip" 
  android:id="@+id/textView1" 
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
  android:paddingTop="30dip"></TextView>
   <TextView 
    android:text="Shopping Lists" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="40px" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="25dip" 
    android:id="@+id/textView2" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="40px"
        android:layout_y="35px">
 <ScrollView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget54"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="15.0" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button 
        android:text="New Project" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:textColorHighlight="#ff0000">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Manage Projects" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button2">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Done" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button3">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every xml file needs to have a name space for it which is defined in the root tag of the xml file using the xmlns . So the suggestion by woodshy is exactly what you need ,add a : `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` to the first LinearLayout in your xml file.

Answer (score 1):

add xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to root LinearLayout